# Don't match regex when variable is empty

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have the following file

```
more /etc/hosts
23.1.22.162 kafka01.dfg.com
23.1.22.155 kafka02.dfg.com
23.1.22.222 kafka03.dfg.com
23.1.22.111 master01.dfg.com
23.1.22.239 master02.dfg.com
23.1.22.170 master03.dfg.com
23.1.22.167 worker01.dfg.com
23.1.22.165 worker02.dfg.com
23.1.22.112 worker03.dfg.com
```

We want to capture all `master` and `worker` machines when `kafka_name=""` with `egrep` so we did that

```
kafka_name=""
egrep "\smaster|\sworker|\s$kafka_name"  /etc/hosts
```

but we still get hosts included kafka machines as

```
 egrep "\smaster|\sworker|\s$kafka_name"  /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
23.1.22.162 kafka01.dfg.com
23.1.22.155 kafka02.dfg.com
23.1.22.222 kafka03.dfg.com
23.1.22.111 master01.dfg.com
23.1.22.239 master02.dfg.com
23.1.22.170 master03.dfg.com
23.1.22.167 worker01.dfg.com
23.1.22.165 worker02.dfg.com
23.1.22.112 worker03.dfg.com
```

anyway when we set

```
kafka_name="kafka"
```

we also get the kafka machines as

```
egrep "\smaster|\sworker|\s$kafka_name"  /etc/hosts
23.1.22.162 kafka01.dfg.com
23.1.22.155 kafka02.dfg.com
23.1.22.222 kafka03.dfg.com
23.1.22.111 master01.dfg.com
23.1.22.239 master02.dfg.com
23.1.22.170 master03.dfg.com
23.1.22.167 worker01.dfg.com
23.1.22.165 worker02.dfg.com
23.1.22.112 worker03.dfg.com
```

so why when we set

```
kafka_name=""
```

does it still print the kafka machines from hosts despite `$kafka_name` being null?

Comment: When `$kafka_name` is empty, you're matching an empty string, which matches everything.

Comment: I see , so what is the right solution in order to fix it

Comment: `\s` if it's meant to mean `[[:space:]]` is PCRE syntax, not ERE syntax. `egrep` isn't guaranteed to honor it at all (some versions do, but the standard doesn't require it).

Comment: One solution is to set `kafka_name="periodontic-manipulation"` or to any other value that you're confident won't appear in the hosts file.  Then that alternative will never match anything instead of matching everything.  A more elegant way might be `egrep "\smaster|\sworker${kafka_name:+|\s}$kafka_name" /etc/hosts` which only adds the `|\s` if `$kafka_name` is non-empty.

Comment: @jessica, ...anyhow, considered anchoring your match?

Comment: also if I removed the |\s then I get the same situation

Comment: That is: `'[[:space:]](master|worker|'"$kafka_name"')([[:space:]]|$)'` -- the `$` at the end means that an empty string won't match unless your file has lines ending in whitespace.

Comment: Or ditch `grep` altogether and use `awk`; `awk -v kafka_name="$kafka_name" '$2 == "master" || $2 == "worker" || $2 == kafka_name'`

Comment: Note that POSIX only specifies [`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). Use `grep -E` to obtain the functionality of `egrep` (and `grep -F` to get the functionality of `fgrep`): _This grep has been enhanced in an upwards-compatible way to provide the exact functionality of the historical_ egrep _and_ fgrep _commands as well. … _The old_ egrep _and_ fgrep _commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`.

Consider using awk instead, though, for clear, simple control over whatever conditions (not just regexps - conditions) you want to express, e.g.:

```
$ kafka_name=''
$ awk -v kafka_name="$kafka_name" '( $2 ~ /^(master|worker)/ ) || ( (kafka_name != "") && ($2 ~ ("^"kafka_name)) )' file
23.1.22.111 master01.dfg.com
23.1.22.239 master02.dfg.com
23.1.22.170 master03.dfg.com
23.1.22.167 worker01.dfg.com
23.1.22.165 worker02.dfg.com
23.1.22.112 worker03.dfg.com
```

```
$ kafka_name='kafka02'
$ awk -v kafka_name="$kafka_name" '( $2 ~ /^(master|worker)/ ) || ( (kafka_name != "") && ($2 ~ ("^"kafka_name)) )' file
23.1.22.155 kafka02.dfg.com
23.1.22.111 master01.dfg.com
23.1.22.239 master02.dfg.com
23.1.22.170 master03.dfg.com
23.1.22.167 worker01.dfg.com
23.1.22.165 worker02.dfg.com
23.1.22.112 worker03.dfg.com
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box.

It is using regexp rather than string comparisons, though, just like in your `egrep` command was doing, and so if any of those names can contain regexp metachars you'd need to escape them or change the script to use `index($2,string) == 1` everywhere instead of `$2 ~ /^regexp/`, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v kafka_name="$kafka_name" '(index($2,"master") == 1) || (index($2,"worker") == 1) || ( (kafka_name != "") && (index($2,kafka_name) == 1) )' file
23.1.22.155 kafka02.dfg.com
23.1.22.111 master01.dfg.com
23.1.22.239 master02.dfg.com
23.1.22.170 master03.dfg.com
23.1.22.167 worker01.dfg.com
23.1.22.165 worker02.dfg.com
23.1.22.112 worker03.dfg.com
```

Answer (score 2):

When `$kafka_name` is empty, the pattern is `"\smaster|\sworker|\s"`, and the last alternative matches any line with a space, so it matches everything.

One option is to set `$kafka_name` to something you know will never exist instead of an empty string, e.g.

```
kafka_name=kafkaXXXX
```

Another is to add `$kafka_name` to the pattern only when it's not empty.

```
pattern="\smaster|\sworker"
if [ -n "$kafka_name" ]
then pattern="$pattern|\s$kafka_name"
fi
egrep "$pattern" /etc/hosts
```

Comment: As I noted in a comment to the question, another way might be `egrep "\smaster|\sworker${kafka_name:+|\s}$kafka_name" /etc/hosts` which only adds the `|\s` if `$kafka_name` is neither empty nor undefined.

Comment: Using `\s` makes this unnecessarily particular about which `grep` implementations will work with it. Granted, we know the OP is currently using an implementation that's okay with that, but it'd make their code more portable to other platforms to switch to `[[:space:]]`